# how to approach moving custom images around the screen using the gloss library

Tags: haskell, io, gloss

I am trying to build a simple game in gloss that uses BMP files for sprites that will be animated and moved around after being loaded.  I am trying to get a few of these images of them to move using the animate or simulate functions.

One of the parameters of simulate is of type (model -> Picture) (i.e. a function that takes a user defined data type storing the state of the game and returning a Picture), while the loadBMP function typically used to load files is loadBMP :: FilePath -> IO Picture.

Having some trouble grasping what exactly I should be doing at a higher level to get the images to move, particularly given that loadBMP would return Picture IO not Picture. Any ideas?  Sorry if this wasn't specific enough.

```
module Main(main) where

import Graphics.Gloss
import System.IO  
import Control.Monad
import Graphics.Gloss.Data.ViewPort

data GameState = State{ 
      boardpic::Picture
    , ballpic :: Picture
    , ballCoords :: (Float, Float)  
    , ballSpeed :: (Float, Float) 
    , paddle1pic::Picture  
    , p1Coords :: (Float, Float)
    , paddle2pic::Picture
    , p2Coords:: (Float,Float)
    , paused::Bool
    , turnscore::Integer                                  
    } deriving (Show) 

moveBall time state = state {ballCoords = (xnew, ynew)} 
    where
    (xposbefore, yposbefore) = ballCoords state 
    (xspeed, yspeed) = ballSpeed state
    (xnew, ynew) = (xposbefore + xspeed*time, yposbefore+xspeed*time)

render::GameState->Picture
render state =  
  pictures[board, 
           paddle1, 
           paddle2,
           ball]
  where
    board = boardpic state
    ball = translate 0 0 $ ballpic state
    paddle1 = translate (-300) 0 $ paddle1pic state
    paddle2 = translate 300 0 $ paddle2pic state  

--calculates running sum of score for the player from list 
score xs = tail.reverse $ foldl f [0] xs 
  where 
    f (y:ys) x = (x+y):y:ys
 
window :: Display
window = InWindow "SuperPong" (800, 800) (0,0)

background::Color
background = blue

fps :: Int
fps = 60
    
printState::GameState->IO ()
printState state = do
  putStrLn $ show $ boardpic state
  putStrLn $ show $ ballpic state
  putStrLn $ ("ball coordinates: ")++(show $ ballCoords state)
  putStrLn $ ("paddle1 coords:  " )++(show $ p1Coords state)
  putStrLn $ ("paddle2 coords: " )++(show $ p2Coords state)
  putStrLn $ ("paused or not: " ) ++ (show $ paused state)
  putStrLn $ ("score: " )++(show $ turnscore state)

--paddlecollision::

--outofbounds::

main :: IO ()
main = do
  pad1 <- loadBMP "paddle1.bmp"
  pad2 <- loadBMP "paddle2.bmp"
  board <- loadBMP "board.bmp"
  ball1 <- loadBMP "ball.bmp"

  let initstate = State{
    boardpic = board
  , ballpic = ball1
  , ballCoords = (-10, 10)
  , ballSpeed = (50, -50)
  , paddle1pic = pad1
  , p1Coords = (-300, 0)
  , paddle2pic = pad2
  , p2Coords = (300, 0)
  , paused = False
  , turnscore = 0
  }
    
  let update _ = moveBall 
  
  printState initstate
  let allpics = render initstate     

  simulate window background fps initstate render update
```

updated

Comment: Load the bitmap at the beginning of `main` and store the resulting `Picture` in your `model`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to update your state as you go. `animate` doesn't do that. If you want to use `animate`, you must always compute the current picture given *only* a timestamp (though of course you can close over your model to include whatever other static data you want). If you'd like to iteratively update your state, you should use `simulate` instead.

Comment: thanks, updated the code.  any reason you can see why the ball isnt moving?

Comment: Where are you using `ballCoords`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your game logic, but the following code can let your ball move.

```hs
render::GameState->Picture
render state =  
  pictures[board, 
           paddle1, 
           paddle2,
           ball]
  where
    board = boardpic state
    -- ball = translate 0 0 $ ballpic state
    ball = translate (fst (ballCoords state)) (snd (ballCoords state)) $ ballpic state
    paddle1 = translate (-300) 0 $ paddle1pic state
    paddle2 = translate 300 0 $ paddle2pic state
```